# k8s in Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

1. In my Jenkins pipeline the user should select machine name from "Choice Parameter". Let's say there are 2 machines: machine1 and machine2.

The next parameter should be dynamic Kubernetes namespaces list. I suppose I need to use "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter", that will run "kubectl get namespaces" command on selected machine: machine1 or machine2. The result of this command should appear as a list parameter for selection.

I googled a lot, but didn't succeed to make it running. Pls advise.

2. How can I debug "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter"? If I use in "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" println command, where it will appear?

Comment: Please share your code with us, so we can understand what you are trying.

Comment: I tried the following. But it should run on selected machine (machine1 or machine2) and I don't know how to set it:

def command = "kubectl get namespaces"
def proc =command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              
def ns = proc.in.text

return ns

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect with different machines from the groovy code that you have shared.
The command is still running on the same machine where your jenkins job is running and getting list of cluster from the same machine.
you can set multiple clusters in your kubectl config and run the kubectl command accordingly.

Code logic should be -

```
if selected_machine = machine1
kubectl config use-context machine1;kubectl get ns
```

further we can explore Kubernetes API to interact with the cluster and get the NS for cluster accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Virendra. But in the pipeline code itself, we use something like below. Can't we somehow set the agent in "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" script as well?
pipeline {
    agent {
        machine1
    }
...